What's a good way to represent equivalence classes of matrices in python?
I'm trying to write a program to do reinforcement learning for tic-tac-toe. I want the engine to recognize that if you reflect a board or rotate it you get the exact same game, so that these boards should be considered the same as each other.
Currently I have a dictionary representing my current estimate valuation for each board in the game, and every time a game finishes the valuations of all the board positions that occured during that game get updated according to whether they resulted in a win or resulted in a loss.
I want a way to have it so that all the rotations and reflections get grouped together, so that an update for one updates all the other ones as well.
My current strategy is to generate all the possible rotations and reflections of a board, stick them in a set, then turn this set into a frozenset so I can use it as a key in a dictionary. I think this should work, but something feels very dodgy about using frozen sets.
I am curious what other approaches there could be to this problem. And also if my feeling of frozen sets being 'dodgy', has any merit, or is just some silly mental block I should get over. I often feel this whenever I use a python construction of some kind that is not well known.

Since the board is being used as a state in your value or action-value table, I would try to build a canonical representation of the board state that is invariant to rotations and reflections.
Let's call this function get_canonical_state. One could implement get_canonical_state by finding all the transformations of the board with rotations and reflections and returning the min() one. This will ensure that it's always one unique one that gets called "canonical".

def get_canonical_state(board: list[str]) -> str:
  # assuming `board` is a flattened 1-d array like ['x', 'o', '', ....]
  transformations = get_all_transformations(board)
  return min(transformations)


def get_all_transformations(board: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:
  # you seem to know how to write this



So then whenever you want to work with your board state in your RL algorithm, you must always do
state = get_canonical_state(board)
# you might need to use tuple(state) if you want to hash and store this in a dict

and then use this canonical state in your value or action-value table. This would shrink your state space significantly and achieve faster convergence.
